# How to read a keyword from a txt file in zabbix

Tags: files, zabbix

I want to know is there are any solution for my to read the word "Error" from a txt file on solaris and Alert me where the Error is found. I tried to create a item of type zabbix agent active but it did not work please help

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and an example of the log that failed?

Answer (score 1):

Use [log file monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items). For example:

```
logrt["/export/home/user/file.txt","Error",,1]
```

You can then set a trigger on it, if you wish:

```
{myserver.example.com:logrt["/export/home/user/file.txt","Error",,1].nodata(600)}=0
```

A [tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/notify-errors-log-file-zabbix) is available on the Internet that expands on this a bit.

Comment: Hi Michael, should item be of type Zabbix Agent Active?

Comment: Yes, it should be active.